# pandas fuzzy match on the same column but prevent matching against itself

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

This is a common question but I have an extra condition: how do I remove matches based on a unique ID? Or, how to prevent matching against itself?

Given a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 2, 3],
                   'name':['pizza','pizza toast', 'ramen']})
```

[image]

I used solutions like this one to create a multi-index dataframe:

[Fuzzy match strings in one column and create new dataframe using fuzzywuzzy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865890/fuzzy-match-strings-in-one-column-and-create-new-dataframe-using-fuzzywuzzy)

```
df_copy = df.copy()

compare = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['name'], df_copy['name']]).to_series()

def metrics(tup):
    return pd.Series([fuzz.ratio(*tup),
                      fuzz.token_sort_ratio(*tup)],
                     ['ratio', 'token'])

compare.apply(metrics)
```

[image]

So that's great but how can I use the unique ID to prevent matching against itself?

If there's a case of ID/name = 1/pizza and 10/pizza, obviously I want to keep those. But I need to remove the same ID in both indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a slightly different approach for the same result using Python standard library [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) module, which provides helpers for computing deltas.

So, with the following dataframe in which `pizza` has **two different ids** (and thus should be checked against one another later on):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"id": [1, 2, 3, 4], "name": ["pizza", "pizza toast", "ramen", "pizza"]}
)
```

Here is how you can **find similarities** between different id/name combinations, but **avoid** checking an id/name combination against itself:

```py
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

# Define a simple helper function
def ratio(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
```

And then, with the following steps:

```py
# Create a column of unique identifiers: (id, name)
df["id_and_name"] = list(zip(df["id"], df["name"]))

# Calculate ratio only for different id_and_names
df = df.assign(
    match=df["id_and_name"].map(
        lambda x: {
            value: ratio(x[1], value[1])
            for value in df["id_and_name"]
            if x[0] != value[0] or ratio(x[1], value[1]) != 1
        }
    )
)

# Format results in a readable fashion
df = (
    pd.DataFrame(df["match"].to_list(), index=df["id_and_name"])
    .reset_index(drop=False)
    .melt("id_and_name", var_name="other_id_and_name", value_name="ratio")
    .dropna()
    .sort_values(by=["id_and_name", "ratio"], ascending=[True, False])
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    .pipe(lambda df_: df_.assign(ratio=df_["ratio"] * 100))
    .pipe(lambda df_: df_.assign(ratio=df_["ratio"].astype(int)))
)
```

You get the expected result:

```py
print(df)
# Output
         id_and_name other_id_and_name  ratio
0         (1, pizza)        (4, pizza)    100
1         (1, pizza)  (2, pizza toast)     62
2         (1, pizza)        (3, ramen)     20
3   (2, pizza toast)        (4, pizza)     62
4   (2, pizza toast)        (1, pizza)     62
5   (2, pizza toast)        (3, ramen)     12
6         (3, ramen)        (4, pizza)     20
7         (3, ramen)        (1, pizza)     20
8         (3, ramen)  (2, pizza toast)     12
9         (4, pizza)        (1, pizza)    100
10        (4, pizza)  (2, pizza toast)     62
11        (4, pizza)        (3, ramen)     20
```

Comment: This is a great solution, thank you. It seems to be faster than what I tried before. Is that because map is faster than apply?

Comment: Thank you. Hard to say without profiling the code, but I don't think it has to do with map/apply. I'd say performance is improved by using standard library module instead of fuzzywuzzy. Cheers.